How can I use the selected option value of a select element in Pug/Jade template
I have this select in Pug/Jade
select.form-select.col-xs-12.col-sm-12(id='selState1', onClick='+setState(selState1.value)')
                  option(value='selState1', name='selState1',id='selState1') Enter state
                  each state in nigeria.states()
                    option(value='state') #{state} 


Now I need to use the value of the selected option as a parameter in function nigeria.lgas() that generates the options for another select
I have done
 select.form-select.col-xs-12.col-sm-12(id='selLG1', name='selLG1')
                  option.active(value='selLG') Enter Local Government
                    each lg in nigeria.lgas(selState1.value)                      
                      option(value=lg) #{lg}

I get the error 'selState1 is not defined'

Have you tried to replace selState1.value with selLG1.value?

No that doesnt do it. nigeria.lgas() function uses the selected state from the first select as parameter.
